# What is the unit for GeoCoordinateWatcher's GeoPosition Speed value? Is it in m/s or km/hr?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on a Windows Phone 7 project, in which I have to use the GeoCoordinateWatcher class for tracking the user's location and the speed.
But I could not find any documentation which mention the Unit of GeoCoordinateWatcher's GeoPosition Speed value? Is it in m/s or km/hr?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: if i am not mistaken the last time i used GeoCoordinateWatcher it was in m/s. might have to check up on that, because meters/second is the international units of vel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GeoCoordinate.Speed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.speed.aspx)'s documentation (right at the top) states:

> Gets or sets the speed in meters per second.